# How do I loop in an Excel workbook for each cell of a certain color?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Looking to create an Excel VBA loop to go through the active workbook.

1. I need it to create a table for each instance of a blue cell. Basically searche for blue cell, then create a table with touching cells that have contents. I'm able to do this manually using search function and then Ctrl+t.
2. It then needs to create a templated chart for that table (I have a specific chart I want it to use).
3. Then it finds the next blue cell and repeats steps 1 and 2.

I've tried to do a lot of this manually in creating a macro, but it's limited to me entering in specific criteria over and over. Below is the inefficient code. I have to manually enter that I want to search for blue cell, create table, and create chart over and over. Below is an example of entering it three times.

```
Sub CreateGraphTableForEachBlueCell2()
'
' CreateGraphTableForEachBlueCell2 Macro
'

'
    Range("A1").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=True).Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$2:$D$5"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table12"
    Range("Table12[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
        "C:\Users\SAMPLELOCATION.crtx" _
        )
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet3!$A$2:$D$5")
    Range("A3").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=True).Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$H$9:$K$12"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table13"
    Range("Table13[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
        "C:\Users\SAMPLELOCATION.crtx" _
        )
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet3!$H$9:$K$12")
    Selection.Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=True).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: If you don't know which cells are blue, you have to loop all the possible cells. Inside your loop, you ask for the cell color. If blue = process, If NO Blue = No process. Where is the problem exactly?

Comment: It's still not clear where the problem is. Does the code in the question work? Why are certain cells being *selected*? Do these have something specific to do with what follows (if yes, please explain)? If this should all be in a loop, the logic for the difference in the ranges used in the various methods needs to be explained. And the third time doesn't use all the same steps. You first need to work out what's the same, what's different (and why) - get the logic straight before trying to write the code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to do too much all at once.  Let's get the color copying part locked down, and then come back and try to code up the next step.

This will look through all used calls on a sheet and copy/paste all red cells to another sheet.

```
Function is_it_red(i As Long) As Boolean
is_it_red = False
For j = 1 To Columns.Count
If Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
is_it_red = True
Exit Function
End If
Next
End Function


Sub ColorCopier()
Dim i As Long
k = 1
Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
For i = 1 To nLastRow
If is_it_red(i) Then
Set rc = Cells(i, 1).Cells
Set rd = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(k, 1)
rc.Copy rd
k = k + 1
End If
Next
End Sub
```